# Custom bind between vm and uiviewcontroller using mvvm cross v3

Tags: binding, mvvmcross

we just switched to mvvm cross v3 and therefore doing some maintenance on our code. In the earlier version we have done some bindings like this

```
this.AddBindings(
            new Dictionary<object, string>()
                {
                    { this.TopbarBackground, this.UmbracoImageBinding("TopBarImage") },

                    { this,this.Binding("ShowProgressbar","FeedbackIndicatorVisible")}
                });
```

However I am having issue doing { this,this.Binding("ShowProgressbar","FeedbackIndicatorVisible")} in v3. ShowProgressbar is a property on the uiviewcontroller and FeedbackIndicatorVisible is a property on the viewmodel. Both properties are of bool type. I tried doing it like this.CreateBinding().For("ShowProgressbar").To("FeedbackIndicatorVisible").Apply(); but his gives an *Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry*.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code: https://github.com/slodge/QuickTest and it seems to work.

If your problem persists, can you include any more detail about the view or viewmodel - can you maybe provide a full reproduction example of the issue?

Comment: Hi stuart, apparently I was doing some tiny error, because when using your example it worked flawless. Thank you for the help